# Intermittent POST Body Truncation in Spring Boot from React Native App Using RNFS

Tags: spring-boot, react-native

I'm encountering intermittent issues where the POST body gets truncated when sending requests from a React Native app using RNFS to convert multiple images into base64 and include them in the POST body.

However, sometimes the server (Spring Boot) receives these requests with the body partially missing, leading to `HttpMessageNotReadableException` and JSON parse error: `java.io.EOFException`.

Oddly, re-encoding the same images and resending the request often succeeds. My Spring Boot application.yml is configured to accept large POST sizes *(up to 100MB for both max-http-post-size and max-swallow-size)*.

What might be causing this intermittent truncation of the POST body?

yml server:
port:
tomcat:
connection-timeout:
max-http-post-size: 100MB
max-swallow-size: 100MB
threads:
max:

@RequestBody FileRequestArray fileRequestArray,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.